# How to change root background color of react app

Tags: css, reactjs, mobile

[image: Screenshot showing unwanted white background]

I've built a react website and on desktop everything looks perfectly fine, when u scroll past the navigation bar the background remains the same gray color. However on mobile the left and right edges are white as well as if u scroll up past the navigation bar you are able to see a white background. Does anyone know the solution to this? I've set the `background-color` in my css for App, html, and body however none of them seemed to have fixed the issue.
Here is my css:

```
/* .App,
.App-header,
html {
  background-color: #282c34;
} */

.App {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #282c34;
}

.logo {
  width: auto;
  height: 20px;
}

.title,
.body-text {
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: darkgrey;
}

html {
  /* padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px; */
  background-color: #282c34;
}

body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.projectImage {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.project-thumbnail-reg {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  min-width: 400px;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.project-thumbnail-sm {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.project-thumbnail-reg:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.project-thumbnail-sm:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  background-color: rgb(31, 28, 28);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.itemText {
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

#project-title {
  /* padding-bottom: 35px; */
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#project-category {
  /* padding-top: 30px; */
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
}

.formLabel {
  color: whitesmoke;
}

#inlineMessageSuccess {
  color: green;
}
#inlineMessageFail {
  color: red;
}

.PageNotFound {
  color: darkgrey;
  padding-top: 150px;
  font-size: 50pt;
}
```

and here is my App.js:

```
import React from "react";

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Redirect,
  Switch,
} from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "./Pages/Home";
import Projects from "./Pages/Projects";
import Contact from "./Pages/Contact";
import ProjectPage from "./Pages/ProjectPage";
import PageNotFound from "./Pages/PageNotFound";

import { LinkContainer } from "react-router-bootstrap";
import { Navbar, Nav } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./App.css";

import logo from "./assets/logo/logo_trans.png";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Navbar fixed="top" bg="dark" variant="dark">
          <Navbar.Brand style={{ alignContent: "center" }}>
            <img src={logo} className="logo" alt="" />
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Nav className="mr-auto">
            <LinkContainer to="/home">
              <Nav.Link>Home</Nav.Link>
            </LinkContainer>
            <LinkContainer to="/projects">
              <Nav.Link>Projects</Nav.Link>
            </LinkContainer>
            <LinkContainer to="/contact">
              <Nav.Link>Contact</Nav.Link>
            </LinkContainer>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar>
        {/* Router Setup */}
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Redirect to="/home" />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/projects" component={Projects} />
          <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact} />
          <Route path="/project/:id" component={ProjectPage} />
          <Route path="*" component={PageNotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Could you post your code as a snippet? It's tough to provide advice without seeing the source.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an issue with your CSS, the width and possbly height of ex. Body isn't scaling well? It's not easy to tell without some code to look at.

Comment: sure thing, i included a blurb of the css. I tried removing the padding in body and bodytext that i was using but it didnt seem to make a difference.

Comment: Have you tried setting the width of body, or .App? to 100% or 100vw

Comment: ya i have, unfortunately no luck there

Answer (score 0):

The body tag has a default margin, have you tried to set the body's margin to 0?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your answer is not relevant to question. Always be clear of your answers before answering them.